# Headless Selenium replacing file that is being downloaded

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using selenium headless to download files from dropdown options.
As the files are being downloaded after each iteration the first file is getting replaced.

When disabling the headless mode the files get downloaded as I want it a.csv(1), a.csv(2), a.csv(3),

My chrome options are as follows

```
options = webdriver.ChromeOptions() 
options.add_argument('--no-sandbox')
options.add_argument('--headless')
options.add_argument('--disable-dev-shm-usage')
prefs = {"download.default_directory" : curr_dir}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
driver=webdriver.Chrome(options=options)
```

Is there a way to have a behavior similar to non headless mode. Or do I manually rename files after they are downloaded.

Comment: you can check this  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IUOl4W_3tTg

Answer (score 1):

Make options.add_argument('--headless') as options.add_argument('--headless=new') or options.add_argument('--headless=old')

Ref: https://developer.chrome.com/articles/new-headless/

Comment: How does this answer the question? It's unclear what this does to fix it.